# Getting around "OverflowError: Overflow in int64 addition"

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm working in Pandas trying to subtract two columns of dates to get the length of time between them (in months preferably, but any smaller unit would be fine). My original dataframe has over 90,000 rows so I'm working with a trimmed version of my dataframe with about 2,000. This is bad news because I'm running to issues of excessive size (I think???) on the SMALLER dataframe.

Here is the head of my data:

```
     Variety        CropYear      DatePurchased         birthDate
0  AU Vic Secret™      2014  2016-03-01 23:51:27.822    2016-03-01
1  AU Vic Secret™      2014  2016-03-02 22:22:33.285    2016-03-01
2  AU Vic Secret™      2014  2016-03-04 17:03:33.247    2016-03-01
3  AU Vic Secret™      2014  2016-03-04 20:09:35.840    2016-03-01
4  AU Vic Secret™      2014  2016-03-07 14:09:36.502    2016-03-01
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> OverflowError: Overflow in int64 addition

```
data["birthDate"] = pd.to_datetime(data["birthDate"])

data["DatePurchased"] = pd.to_datetime(data["DatePurchased"])

data["Age"] = data["DatePurchased"] - data["birthDate"]
```

I then tried to add `.dt.date` to the first two rows because I saw that in another post on this site and hoped blindly it would work. It produced this error

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

```
data["birthDate"] = pd.to_datetime(data["birthDate"]).dt.date

data["DatePurchased"] = pd.to_datetime(data["DatePurchased"]).dt.date

data["Age"] = data["DatePurchased"] - data["birthDate"]
```

What do these errors mean? How can I get around these issues, especially for a dataframe as large as 90-100 thousand rows?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the days, rather than the longer format '0 days ...' that you get if you subtract the 2 datetime columns as you currently do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DatePurchased':['2016-03-01 23:51:27.822', '2016-03-02 22:22:33.285', '2020-05-20 03:52:12.739'], 'birthDate': ['2016-03-01', '2016-03-01', '2019-08-01']})

df['DatePurchased'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DatePurchased'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df['birthDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['birthDate'], infer_datetime_format=True)

df['Age'] = df['DatePurchased'] - df['birthDate']
df['Age_days'] = (df['DatePurchased'] - df['birthDate']).dt.days
```

Notice the difference between the age formats:

```
            DatePurchased  birthDate                      Age  Age_days
0 2016-03-01 23:51:27.822 2016-03-01   0 days 23:51:27.822000         0
1 2016-03-02 22:22:33.285 2016-03-01   1 days 22:22:33.285000         1
2 2020-05-20 03:52:12.739 2019-08-01 293 days 03:52:12.739000       293
```

Comment: This almost works, but for some reason the code yielded a bunch of negative values for Age_months. What went wrong? Some DatePurchased values might be earlier than their corresponding birthDate value, and therefore create a negative value, but in your code its occurring when it should be positive (i.e. when DatePurchased is later than birthDate.

Comment: If it would help, I can send you the csv I'm using

Comment: If you specify 2 or 3 examples of the dates that give you negative values, that might be enough to figure it out.

Comment: Example: for DatePurchased = 2020-05-20 03:52:12.739 and birthDate = 2019-08-01 the Age_month = -3 when it should be 9

Comment: Now I get it.  I'll edit the answer, I was subtracting 2 months, e.g., 3 - 8 for March - August, without considering the year.  I don't see a way to get months from the time delta, but days is available.

Comment: Similarly, for  DatePurchased = 2021-03-23 17:47:05.062 and birthDate = 2019-11-01 00:00:00.000 the Age_months = -8 when it should be 4

Comment: Unfortunately that code still gives me the following:   OverflowError: Overflow in int64 addition

Comment: Strange.  How about iterating through chunks of the df, say 1k rows at a time, and see if it crashing on certain rows only?  90k rows of integers should not be a big deal, but maybe there is some huge delta between dates that is giving you a huge amount of days?

Comment: Can you help me figure out how to iterate through the df? I'm very new to python, I'm sorry. Thanks!